# Writing data on a .txt file

Tags: java, swing, java-io

I am trying to store values(typed in text area) into a txt file.
following code is creating program.txt file but data is not being written on it. what am i doing wrong?

also if i want to save those values in a user specified .txt file how can it be done?

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {

                o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("program.txt"));

                o.write(t1.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t2.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t3.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t4.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t5.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t6.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t7.getText());
                o.write(",");

            }
             catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to **close your BufferedWriter**, using [**BufferedWriter#close()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29)

```
o.close();
```

Comment: i can accept in 5 mins :)

Answer (score 3):

For ease, also use [`JTextComponent.write(java.io.Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29).

> also if i want to save those values in a user specified .txt file how can it be done?

Offer the user a `JFileChooser` as seen in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13899359/418556).

[image]

Establish the [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) from the file returned (after checking it ends with `.txt`).

Comment: thanks, but can u help me with the second question too?

Comment: See the update.  Though note that separate questions are best asked on separate threads.  You should accept the answer of  @GanGnaMStYleOverFlow & move on to the next question.

Comment: can you please elaborate little more?

Comment: I want user to create a txt file with a name and location he wants and then write data into it.